# Freshdesk integration with AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, freshdesk

Is that possible if the user create a ticket in freshdesk that needs to be  trigger the AWS lambda function.

Comment: Can it fire a webhook when a user creates a ticket?

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be that hard. I would like to recommend using the following architecture

> 1. FreshDesk Ticket Trigger
> 2. FreshDesk Ticket Trigger Handler Published Message to SNS Topic
> 3. AWS Lambda Configured to SNS Topic as Event Source
> 4. AWS Lambda Code Accepts the SNS topic message (as Input) and performs the necessary processing

The advantages of using SNS rather directly calling Lambda are

> 1. Reducing the exposure of AWS API to only SNS topic and completely sealing rest of the API (IAM Privileges)
> 2. Possibility of Fan-Out Architecture [Multiple Lambda Functions can listen to the same SNS topic - near zero configuration]

Comment: How to handle file upload of attachments to the ticket in such a setup?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing on this topic.

It's possible with [Freshdesk Marketplace app](https://developer.freshdesk.com/v2/docs/quick-start). With [onTicketCreate](https://developer.freshdesk.com/v2/docs/product-events/#onticketcreate) product event, any actions can be written to execute with a Serverless function. It's completely run in Freshworks platform cloud.

If required, it can call your AWS Lambda.